# Is it possible to design SSIS packaged without using some version of Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Due to company policies it's not allowed to have some kind of Visual Studio version. Is it possible to design SSIS packages without have some kind of Visual studio version?

In my opinion. And correct me if i'm wrong:

- SQL Server : This need to have an SSIS instance and a SQL instance. SQL for storing data (not really necessary if you use a difference target) and SSIS for deploy the package to and schedule the refresh of the packages.
- Managment Studio : Not really needed, but handy to maintain the database.
- Tool to create the SSIS package. This can be achieve by:

  1. install data tools : this comes with a Visual Studio shell
  2. install Visual Studio Community : comes with the ability to open and create SSIS projected. It can be deployed from there
  3. install Visual Studio Prof : comes with the ability to open and create SSIS projects. It can be deployed from there
- Data tools is free to use can be used commercially
- Managment Studio is free and can use used commercially
- VS Community is free but can't be used commercially (not even in a pilot)
- VS Prof is not free and can be used commercially
- SQL Server is not free and can be used commercially

Comment: "Due to company policies it's not allowed to have some kind of Visual Studio version" - erm, what?

Comment: if you're not allowed to use visual studio whytf would you use SSIS?

Comment: Yes you can hand code the XML if you like. But this is not a practical option. If you can't use Visual Studio, I suggest you use a different ETL tool. TBH I discourage it's use now because I find the client tools so buggy and dfficult to install

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered not using SSIS? I was in similar scenario as and have migrated to using Windows services (top shelf) deployed with octopus deploy. It's more testable, better deployment experience and it's just c#...Maintenance is much easier. In terms of performance we process ETLs 5 time faster now too.

Comment: Just say No! to SSIS! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Answer of this question is yes ,We can create package using the SQL Server .
Go to the database >Right click on the database>task>Inport or Export>and then there is import Export wizard open to create.
I hope you guys got answer how we can create package without using the Visual Studio.